# Can i use a server PSU on a 24 port switch?

Tags: power-supply, switch

I have got a broken switch, the part that is broken of the switch is the psu, i have a 450w psu from a old server i know it is working and i noticed that they are physically the same, but the original psu is 165w and i would like to know if i can use this 450w psu on the switch.

[image: PSU Picture]

[image: PSU Picture]

Switch

UPDATE
[PSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMENc.jpg)
[PSU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJfNR.jpg)
[image: Switch Picture]

Comment: The one with the blue label supports significantly more input and output Amperage than the other one. You don’t indicate which one is the original PSU. Either way the other unit is clearly not compatible

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the physical connections, and how they are wired. And more amperage is 'fine'. Pins being swapped might now be.

Comment: Just for reference and so we can find it quickly https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c03898362 is the manual and the original PSU Is a HP X331 165W 100-240VAC to 12VDC

Answer (score -3):

**I wouldn't**, but I'd be tempted like you.

- Server teal PSU Output shows            `12V = 38.3 A`
- original orange switch PSU Output shows `12V = 13.75A` I believe

So it **could** overpower & fry your network switch. If I were in your spot I'd look for a new PSU on ebay or some second-hand place. You may also have luck asking this question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) since this is business-class equipment or [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) which are other Stack Exchange sites. Electrical Engineering people may not know server/switches so may want you to use a multi-meter to get measures of the connecting pins going from PSU into equipment.

Comment: No, that is not how power supplies work. The higher spec power supply will not "force" 38.3 A into the switch. It will just supply what the switch needs. The problem is that this combination of J9726A switch and 499249-001 power supply is not one that seems to be supported or documented by HP so there's no guarantee it will work.

Comment: so if i try it it won't fry my switch? if it doesn't work it wont just turn on?

Comment: In simple terms, amperage is *'pulled'* by the device, not *'pushed'* by the PSU. Everything else appears to match - but we can't see the pinout/connectors/rear panel.

Comment: been busy at work, i'll update tomorrow with a pic of the conectors

Comment: Hi everyone i tried the power supply, didn't worked, i think the problem is that the switch is dead, not just its psu.